# How to concatenate files using initial part of filename

Tags: files

I have many files with names in the form

```
username_pattern_suffix.ext
```

where "pattern" is fixed, but there are very many usernames, each with several files (i.e. values of 'suffix'). I'd like concatenate each user's files into a single file, e.g.

```
username.ext
```

to end up with one file per username. Each username contains two underscores`_` and ends with a number, but is variable length.

Comment: `cat *_pattern_* > username.ext`

Comment: They're all in one directory. Each username contains exactly two underscores, so it's everything before the 3rd one.  (Sorry I didn't say.)

Comment: Yes @don, so something like `a_smith_123_pattern_prog1.ext`, ... `a_smith_123_pattern_prog10.ext`, ...`z_jones_456_pattern_q5.ext`,...`z_jones_456_pattern_q7.ext` (where `a_smith_123` is the user name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many files there are you could do something like:

```
for pat in *_pattern_*; do
    cat -- "$pat" >> "${pat%%_pattern_*}".ext
done
```

this will loop over all the files in this directory that contain `_pattern_` and `cat` the contents of each appending to a file whose name is everything before `_pattern_` appears in the string, then adding the `.ext` extension.

If there are too many files this won't work though

Comment: Thanks @Eric , around 10^3 files but this is perfect for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat username_pattern_* > username.ext
```

this will concatenate files in alphabetical or alphanumerical order of suffix portion

unless the username_pattern is not in a uniform format, i.e., either fixed length, or delimited by a special character, it should be quite easy to extract the username_pattern from the file names using `cut` or `awk` and run them thru a `for` loop. Not knowing the exact pattern, it is very hard to guess the specific action.